# Getting jquery to work with MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

It's not happening. I tried linking the scripts normally in _Layout.cshtml with `<script src='@Content.Url("...`, installing Web Optimization and using bundles, and putting `@Scripts.Render()` in the head/body/bottom of _Layout.cshtml and before the `<script>` tag on the relevant page. What am I missing?

**Directory structure**

```
Views
    Shared
        Js
            jquery-1.10.2.js
            jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Views/Shared/Js/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Views/Shared/Js/jquery.color-{version}.js")
    );
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // blah, etc, then:
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
```

I can run the actual javascript/jquery code on JsFiddle, so the validity of what I've written there isn't the problem.

Comment: Does it work when you directly reference jquery without bundler (for eg. from CDN)?

Comment: What does the HTML output look like?

Comment: Why not put them in the Scripts folder?

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek Nope, whether I reference them in the head of _Layout.cshtml or in the body of the page I'm working with.

Comment: @Jonesy Don't have one, and it's not my application so I don't want to add too much to the directory structure when it already has a folder for Js files.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The scripts do not seem to be linked in the HTML output.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Oopes disregard my last reply! I see the jquery script linked in what looks like proper manner (the source path is `Views/Shared/Js/jquery-1.10.2.js`), but there's an error that the script was not found at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working: all I did was move the scripts to a different folder, `Content/Js`, and linked it in via `<script src='@Content.Url("...`. `Content` is on the same directory level as `Views`.

All is well now except that I have no idea why the folder matters.

Answer (score 0):

`BundleCollection` class has `IgnoreList` property, which contains the patterns of files' names, that will not be rendered. By default it ignores names with `min` word. You can clear this list inside your `RegisterBundles`:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Views/Shared/Js/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Views/Shared/Js/jquery.color-{version}.js")
    );
}
```